# How to write a BOOL to plist?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, plist

I'd like to assign a boolean value to a plist file entry.  I'm doing the following:

```
NSString *aBool = realBoolValue ? @"YES" : @"NO";      
[myplist setValue: aBool forKey:@"boolKey"];
[myplist writeToFile: [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent: plistFilePath] atomically:NO];
```

But the assignment never takes.  I'm doing the above because the following doesn't work:

```
[myplist setValue: realBoolValue forKey:@"boolKey"];
```

It gives an incompatible type error.  What am I doing wrong?

-- EDIT ---

plistFilePath is initialized as

```
plistFilePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Library/Preferences/myfile.plist"];
```

Comment: You didn't report how you initialize `plistFilePath`; it could be it is not initialized correctly, or that doesn't exist a file at that path.

Comment: Is the file never outputted or is there a specific problem with that particular key?

If plistFilePath is what you described above you will have a bogus directory since you try to append NSHomeDirectory twice. Moreover, does the directory exist?

Comment: That was exactly the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you eventually write the plist? `[myplist writeToFile:plistFilePath atomically:YES];`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can wrap it in a NSNumber object:

```
  [NSNumber numberWithBool:yourBool]
```

Use [NSNumber boolValue] when reading back the value from the plist.

Comment: Thanks. That does the correct conversion but the value still isn't saving into the plist.  The path is correct.  I'm running it in Xcode on the simulator.  Do you have any ideas what could be wrong? It should throw an error if the path or key names are incorrect right?

Comment: Yes - it is a NSMutableDictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
[NSNumber numberWithBool:yourBool]
```

If you do so, you will get a number when you call `objectForKey@"boolKey"`.
But if you add the bool for key in the plist file, you will get an **NSCFBoolen**.